# linux bash script error handling for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm having trouble working out a bash script. I'm writing an script to copy multiple files and then change an internal word with `sed` command (for example = `a/x`) but it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash 
for (( i = 20151122; i <=20151131; i++)) 
do 
  for (( j = 20151122; j <=20151131; j++)) 
  do 
    cp ~/lecture_2015_11_21.stream.smil "lecture_$i.stream.smil"; 
    cd ~/ 
    sed -i 's/$i/$j/g' lecture$j.stream.smil 
  done 
done
```

Comment: Please indicate in your question what you have tried, and the (expected) output. See [how to ask a good question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Mak, you need to formulate your questions in a better way. Also, you tagged javascript on a shell script question.

Comment: What is your code and what is the error?

Comment: it is my first time to use  a stackoverflow so i am learning write now and my ques is that i want to copy a mulptile files in a directory and then i want  to rename a some word or date inside that file

Comment: my code is :-     #!/bin/bash

 for (( i = 20151122; i <=20151131; i++))
  do

for (( j = 20151122; j <=20151131; j++))
do

     cp ~/lecture_2015_11_21.stream.smil "lecture_$i.stream.smil";
    cd ~/
      sed -i 's/$i/$j/g' lecture$j.stream.smil
done
done

Comment: in this only one loop is working can u tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

For sed, to get the values from bash, you have to use, instead of single quotes, double quotes (it's primarly a bash-quoting question):

wrong:

```
sed -i 's/$i/$j/g' lecture$j.stream.smil
```

right:

```
sed -i "s/$i/$j/g" lecture$j.stream.smil
```

In this case you can omit them all together:

```
 sed -i s/$i/$j/g lecture$j.stream.smil
```

Comment: it has nothing to do with `sed`. It's how quoted string work in *bash*.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I know. I think that's what I wrote but added some additional words to emphasize it.